# PHP mb_convert_encoding doesn't work

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I have a trouble with encoding type. There is my code and it's in both of echo's returning ASCII, but i need to set it as UTF-8. Do you have any ideas?

```
 mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
 $a = "some string";
 echo mb_detect_encoding($a);
 mb_convert_encoding($a, "UTF-8", "ASCII");
 echo mb_detect_encoding($a);
```

Comment: Every ASCII string is also a valid UTF-8 string. `mb_detect_encoding()` is correct in this case.

Comment: Why do you even want `mb_detect_encodig` to say it's UTF8?

Comment: @jreuab My problem is that, I'm trying to put some UTF-8 strings from Android through PHP script to mysql, but in database table instead polish characters i'm getting "?".

Comment: Well, using the `org.apache.http` your POSTs contain UTF-8 encoded strings. You just need to set the mysql encoding to use UTF-8. You could use `mysql_set_charset` to do that.